# How to always get the same instance of parent class in php

Tags: php, oop

I have controller classes that are children of a primary controller class.
If I instantiate a controller inside another controller the primary controller gets instantiated again for each controller called.

I have tried creating a static instance but I don't think I am doing it right.

```
class Controller {
    private static $instance;

    public function __construct() {
            self::$instance =& $this;
            echo 1; 
     }
}

class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function index() {   
        $header = new HeaderController();
    }
}

class HeaderController extends Controller {
    public function index() {   
    }
}

$home = new HomeController();
```

I echo 1 in the parent controller so when I instantiate the home(child) controller the output is 11. So for each child controller instance another 1 is added. I assume this means I'm getting a new instance of the parent controller over and over.

Is this a inefficient/bad? If it is, how can I get the same instance of the parent controller always?

Comment: I don't write any php but, this seems like a case for the singleton pattern.  Ref: https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php

Comment: I suggest adding codeigniter tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In a way* you are getting a new instance of the parent controller each time you instantiate a class that extends it, because an instance of the child class is also an instance of the parent class, but a separate additional new instance of the parent controller is not created when you instantiate an object of the child class.

In other words, `HomeController` and `HeaderController` do not each *have* a `Controller`, but they both *are* `Controller`s.

The child class extends the parent class. That means that it inherits all of its methods, including the constructor, and each time the constructor is called, you'll see another output of 1. But that doesn't mean that another instance of the parent controller was created.

Comment: In other words, dont panic this is not an issue?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's an issue. I think what you're seeing is just normal behavior for inheritance, and not anything to worry about.